# Convert Scientific Notation to Float

Tags: python, decimal, notation

Encountered a problem whereby my JSON data gets printed as a scientific notation instead of a float.

```
import urllib2
import json
import sys

url = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-quid'
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
QUID_data = json.load(json_obj)

QUID_MarketName_Trex = QUID_data["result"][0]["MarketName"][4:9]
QUID_Last_Trex = QUID_data["result"][0]["Last"]
QUID_High_Trex = QUID_data["result"][0]["High"]
QUID_Low_Trex = QUID_data["result"][0]["Low"]
QUID_Volume_Trex = QUID_data["result"][0]["Volume"]
QUID_BaseVolume_Trex = QUID_data["result"][0]["BaseVolume"]
QUID_TimeStamp_Trex = QUID_data["result"][0]["TimeStamp"]
QUID_Bid_Trex = QUID_data["result"][0]["Bid"]
QUID_Ask_Trex = QUID_data["result"][0]["Ask"]
QUID_OpenBuyOrders_Trex = QUID_data["result"][0]["OpenBuyOrders"]
QUID_OpenSellOrders_Trex = QUID_data["result"][0]["OpenSellOrders"]
QUID_PrevDay_Trex = QUID_data["result"][0]["PrevDay"]
QUID_Created_Trex = QUID_data["result"][0]["Created"]
QUID_Change_Trex = ((QUID_Last_Trex - QUID_PrevDay_Trex)/ QUID_PrevDay_Trex)*100
QUID_Change_Var = str(QUID_Change_Trex)
QUID_Change_Final = QUID_Change_Var[0:5] + '%'

print QUID_Last_Trex
```

It prints the following value; `1.357e-05`. 
I need this to be a float with 8 chars behind the decimal (0.00001370)

As you can see here --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqhNc.jpg, my GUI displays the first row correct (using the exact same code).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You are looking at the *default `str()` formatting* of floating point numbers, where scientific notation is used for sufficiently small or large numbers.

You don't need to convert this, the *value itself* is a proper float. If you need to display this in a different format, [format it *explicitly*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> print(0.00001357)
1.357e-05
>>> print(format(0.00001357, 'f'))
0.000014
>>> print(format(0.00001357, '.8f'))
0.00001357
```

Here the `f` format *always* uses fixed point notation for the value. The default precision is 6 digits; the `.8` instructs the `f` formatter to show 8 digits instead.

In Python 3, the default string format is essentially the same as `format(fpvalue, '.16g')`; the `g` format uses either a scientific or fixed point presentation depending on the exponent of the number. Python 2 used `'.12g'`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use print formatting:

```
x = 1.357e-05    
print('%f' % x)
```

Edit:

```
print('%.08f' % x)
```

Comment: Link to JSON--> https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-quid ## Object LAST reads '0.00001361' right now. Using your solution, it prints '0.000014'. It's rounded up for some reason.

Comment: yes, it is rounded to 6 numbers after the dot. as Martijn Pieters wrote, you can specify it. >>> print('%.08f' % x)

Comment: btw. why  you expect 0.00001370 instead of 0.00001357 for 1.357e-05?

Comment: Thanks! It's an exchange rate for a cryptocurrency, those 2 last decimals make a huge difference, thus why I need all 8 to display. It works now. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 4):

There are some approaches:

---

#1 `float(...)` + optionally `round()` or `.format()`

```
x = float(1.357e-05)
round(x, 6)
"{:.8f}".format(x)
```

---

#2 with `decimal` class

```
import decimal

tmp = decimal.Decimal('1.357e-05')
print('[0]', tmp)
# [0] 0.00001357

tmp = decimal.Decimal(1.357e-05)
print('[1]', tmp)
# [1] 0.0000135700000000000005188384444299032338676624931395053863525390625

decimal.getcontext().prec = 6
tmp = decimal.getcontext().create_decimal(1.357e-05)
print('[2]', tmp)
# [2] 0.0000135700
```

---

#3 with `.rstrip(...)`

```
x = ("%.17f" % n).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

Note: there are counterparts to `%f`:
`%f` shows standard notation
`%e` shows scientific notation
`%g` shows default (scientific if 5 or more zeroes)