# Expanding Int64 data type in dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have read a csv file using pandas and have a feature that is in scientific notation:

3.450 e +04

How can I change the data type here to show the entire number?

I tried changing to a float a few others with no luck

I am using Python 2.7 on Jupyter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099626/python-convert-scientific-notation-to-float

Comment: The issue isn't the data-type, it is how it is being printed.