# How can I suppress the conversion of the float numbers to exponential format?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I make sure the print out in not in exponential format?

```
numbers = [0.001,0.00005,0.00000087]

for number in numbers:
    print(number)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0.001
5e-05
8.7e-07
```

**INTENDED OUTPUT:**

```
0.001
0.00005
0.00000087
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099626/convert-scientific-notation-to-float

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
print "%.8f" % a
```

after `print "%.` you can enter the number of digits after the comma.