# How can I convert scientific notation strings to floats as it is going through a for loop

Tags: python, list

I have a text file, `prob_value.txt` that is generated from a list and holds ints, floats, and scientific notation strings.

ex 4 values. `4 0.004e-2 5.5 0.0`

I need to turn them all into floats so I can plug them into an equation. I can turn ints into floats but i'm not sure how to add the scientific notation to float conversion into my existing code.

```
# grabs the string that fits the regex parameters and writes it to prob_value.txt
# values should be either an int, float, or scientific notation
# then turns them all into floats so I can plug them into an equation
collision_probability1 = re.compile(r"\d+(?:\.\d+(?:e\-+\d+)?)?")
with open("out.txt") as f, open("prob_value.txt", "w") as f_out:
    prob = f.read()
    probability = re.findall(collision_probability1, prob)
    f_out.write(f"{probability[0]}")
    for i in range(1, len(probability)):
        f_out.write(f" {probability[i]}")

        # part I am having trouble with. Any string that matches the regex pattern is 
        # a scientific notation string. As it goes through the for loop, I want the code
        # to convert those strings to a float so when I print(probability)
        # all the outputs are floats. 
        sci_not = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d+e\-+\d+")
        if sci_not:
            float(probability[i])
        probability = list(map(float, probability))
print (probability)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Scientific Notation to Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099626/convert-scientific-notation-to-float)

Comment: `float('0.004e-2')` will convert it to float normally

Comment: yeah that works but the values in the list change so I can't put the actual value in there. I tried using float(probability[i]) but that doesn't work.