# Python multiplying decimals less than 1

Tags: python, floating-point

I am trying to multiply two decimals but Python 3 does not seem to respect the fact the numbers are decimals.

The basic code I have is:

```
val1 = 0.00141643059490085
val2 = 0.00623423464234545
Res  = val1 * val2
print(str(Res))
```

The result I am getting is `8.830360683208854e-06` which obviously is not correct.

It appears to be stripping the decimal and zeros and just multiplying the remaining number.

Comment: Pay attention to the `e-06` part. That's scientific notation, used by default for sufficiently large or small values - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25099656/2337736 for some options to change the formatting.

Comment: Why is it not correct? Do you understand what `e-06` means?

Comment: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation.

Comment: This should really have just been duped to [Convert Scientific Notation to Float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25099626/364696).

Comment: I agree with @MichaelSzczesny, is this the real reason? Because it sounds strange to me... this is not a typo at all.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny: Sometimes people stretch "not reproducible" to mean "the code is actually behaving correctly, the OP just doesn't realize it". In the sense that there is no problem to reproduce. Not endorsing it here (this should have just been duped to one of a few similar questions asked here), but people do it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, should we make a post on MetaStackOverflow about it? This close reason should be added because it happens often.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO: You're welcome to. I've largely avoided Meta so far.

Comment: I'd still give OP props for providing enough code for a clear reproduction and explanation of why they thought it was incorrect (even though they were mistaken).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I've largely avoided Meta too, but I made this [feature-request] post about what we were discussing: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418514/adding-correct-behavior-minsuderstood-to-close-reasons

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO Did you delete the Meta post?

Comment: @CrazyChucky Yes, I thought I needed to since there were 3 downvotes, but I've just undeleted it in case somebody thinks the new close reason is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
8.830360683208854e-06
```

Do you know what does it mean? It's just [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

---

You can read it as the following.

> `8.830360683208854` multiplied by `10` elevated to an exponent of `-6`

---

So the result of the sum is correct, but you may want to format the `float` in a different way, in this case I suggest to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099626/convert-scientific-notation-to-float/25099656#25099656).